# "Can’t get alias of" using applescript

Tags: scripting, applescript, finder

I'm making a script where the variable is set to a folder path. I am telling finder to make an alias of the folder, but I'm getting an error.

```
tell application "Finder"
    make alias of art to desktop
end tell
```

Error: `Can’t get alias of "PATH:TO:FILE"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
set originalFIle to (choose file)
tell application "Finder" to make new alias file to originalFIle at desktop
```

Comment: Nope. A different Error: "Finder got an error: Can’t make class alias file." number -2710 from

Comment: Yep. Worked for me. Mac OS X 10.11.5